# Static methods in an abstract class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, static

I want to define an abstract method like so:

```
public abstract class Saveable {
    public Set<Field> getFieldSet();
    ...
}
```

`getFields()` should always return the same output regardless of the object's state. However, I can't declare this as a static method because I want it to be overridden. Now I'm implementing a class `User` which extends `Saveable` and it has some static methods which require the field set. Obviously, I can't get it because I don't have an object. Any idea on a design that would allow me to get the fields in a static method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be "fake" the `this` reference by passing in an instance of the correct object to the static methods, and then calling `getFields` on that object.

Another option is to store the field list in a static field on the class. Your overridden `getFields()` implementation can return it (or preferably a copy of it,) and your static methods can access it directly.

My preference would be to implement the latter option, as it's a lot less clumsy (since you never have to new up an otherwise useless object to pass in to the static methods.) As well, it captures the idea that the class's fields don't rely on a given instance.

Comment: Given that you explicity state that "`getFields()` should always return the same output regardless of the object's state", the fields they reference should probably be static (and likely final) anyways.  If you absolutely  need the additional separation, you can code an additional, static, `getFields()` method, which you can have the non-static version (and other static methods) call.  Otherwise, the answer @dlev provided would probably be my choice.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately an inherited class **can't** override a static method, but it **can** hide it by declaring an static method with the same signature.

This will not help you if your final purpose is to use the `GetFields()` inside another inherited method in the `Saveable` class, because it will always call `Saveable.getFields()`, not the static method in your extending class.

Comment: He knows that, since he said "However, I can't declare this as a static method because I want it to be overridden." This isn't a helpful answer.

Comment: They are inherited, but not virtual iirc.

Comment: @aioobe So if you have `SpecificSaveable extends Saveable` and `getFields()` would be static, is `SpecificSaveable.getFields()` valid?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I read up on the documentation and I am going to update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave your current method as non-static and abstract in Savable and return a static Set out of the non-static implementation.

```
public class User extends Savable {

    public static Set<AField> aSet = new HashSet<AField>();

    @Override
    public Set<? extends Field> getFields() {
        return aSet;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling a static method, you're calling the class' name as a scope.

So there's actually no meaning of overriding, you're only hiding it anyway.

Besides, because of the same reason, it cannot be inherited because it belongs to the class type, not a class instance.

The best you can do is call the base class' static method in the derived class, and have the same method name.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding @dlev 's answer, how about you store the fields in a hashmap keyed off by unique identifier per class.

If you are using Spring, you can inject the set of fields in every object. Hence only the reference will be duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

This is the proposal, I worked out. But you somehow have to name the derived class name, when loading those fields, there is no other way around, apart from declaring the methods static anyway.

```
public abstract class Saveable {
    public static Set<? extends Field> getFields(Class<? extends Saveable> clazz) {
        return FieldsProvider.get(clazz);
    }
}

public class FieldsProvider {
    private static final Map<Class<? extends Saveable>, Set<? extends Field>> map =
        new HashMap<Class<? extends Saveable>, Set<? extends Field>>();

public static void registerFields(Class<? extends Saveable> clazz, Collection<? extends Field> col) {
    Set<? extends Saveable> set = new HashSet<? extends Saveable>();
    set.addAll(col);
    map.put(clazz, set);
}

public static Set<? extends Field> getFieldSet(Class<? extends Saveable> clazz) {
    Set<? extends Field> set = map.get(clazz);
    if (set != null) {
        return set;
    }
    return Collections.emptySet();
}
}

public class User extends Saveable {
static {
    FieldsProvider.registerFields(User.class, new HashSet<? extends Field>... ;
}

static void someMethod() {
    Set<? extends Field> fieldsSet = getFields(User.class);
    ...
}
}
```